# Activities can't be added until the containing group has been created error throws at addTab

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

I'm working on an Android App and I want to use 4 tabs for navigation using Activites for each tab. here I added the code which I have tried

this is my TabHostActivity

```
public class TabHostActivity extends Activity {


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_host);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
        tabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);

        TabHost.TabSpec tag4= tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_4_TAG);
        TabHost.TabSpec tag3= tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_3_TAG);
        TabHost.TabSpec tag2= tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_2_TAG);
        TabHost.TabSpec tag1= tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_1_TAG);
        tag1.setIndicator("AboutCollege", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.college)).setContent(new Intent(this, AboutCollegeActivity.class));
        tag2.setIndicator("Focus of Course", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.course)).setContent(new Intent(this, AboutCollegeActivity.class));
        tag3.setIndicator("Admision", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.admission)).setContent(new Intent(this, AboutCollegeActivity.class));
        tag4.setIndicator("Contact Details", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.contact)).setContent(new Intent(this, AboutCollegeActivity.class));
        tabHost.addTab(tag1);
        tabHost.addTab(tag2);
        tabHost.addTab(tag3);
        tabHost.addTab(tag4);


    }
}
```

this is my tabHost.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

this is the error log

```
15:41.601 12232-12232/com.after2.svirtzone.after2_gradle
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.after2.svirtzone.after2_gradle/com.after2.svirtzone.after2_gradle.TabHostActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
    Activities can't be added until the containing group has been created.
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activities can't be added until the containing group has been created.
            at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:262)
            at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:820)
            at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:484)
            at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:286)
            at com.after2.svirtzone.after2_gradle.TabHostActivity.onCreate(TabHostActivity.java:70)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5326)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2225)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:158) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

When I click the button from another activity it moves to this tab host. here I got the exception like in the error log. I have searched but unfortunately, I didn't get a clear answer.

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps to U

```
TabActivity
extends ActivityGroup 
java.lang.Object

   ↳    android.content.Context
       ↳    android.content.ContextWrapper
           ↳    android.view.ContextThemeWrapper
               ↳    android.app.Activity
                   ↳    android.app.ActivityGroup
                       ↳    android.app.TabActivity
```

This class was deprecated in API level 13.
New applications should use Fragments instead of this class; to continue to run on older devices, you can use the v4 support library which provides a version of the Fragment API that is compatible down to DONUT.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html